# Google Glass Application Development

Tags: android, google-glass

I am an Android Developer.
Now, I want to develop an application for the Google Glass.

I had refer the link.
https://developers.google.com/glass/
I had go through the Static Cards and Live Cards link.

I want to make a simple notification application for the google glass. 
In the application, user receives a notification after the interval of 1 minute.

But I don't understand how to start it. If there is any other tutorial links then please suggest me.

Please help.
Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 0):

The Glass app that you're describing is probably best started by a voice command. For example, a person might say "ok glass, start a timer" to start your app.

This process is described at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example which is XE16 friendly and shows how to do low frequency live card updates:

https://github.com/mscheel/GoogleGlass-XE16-LowFrequencyLiveCardBasketballScore

You can follow the commit history to see how I updated an XE12 project to work with XE16.

To do updates once a minute change line 27 of this file to be 60000 -

https://github.com/mscheel/GoogleGlass-XE16-LowFrequencyLiveCardBasketballScore/blob/master/src/com/digitalconstruction/LowFrequencyLiveCardBasketballScore/LiveCardService.java

You should also star this item, which notes that the relevant developer documentation is incorrect and needs to be updated since the XE16 update:

https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=493

That will help those that follow behind you.

Comment: Hello...Mark Thanks for the response. I have install this application. But it giving me the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.glass.timeline.LiveCard

Into the LiveCardService, in onStartCommand Method:
// Get an instance of a live card
   mLiveCard = new LiveCard(this, LIVE_CARD_TAG);

Comment: Hmm ... its working for me.  What XE are you running, I just tested on XE16.2 and it worked.  Maybe try a project clean.  The user in this question said this code worked perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230538/implement-low-frequency-live-card-in-google-glass/23234716#23234716  If you find this helpful please upvote or accept